# How to handle an insertion of an already existing key?

Tags: c++, dictionary

What is the **standard** way to handle an attempt to insert a key into a map that already contains that key?

1. Should an error be thrown?
2. Should the insertion function simply return without adding the key/value pair?
3. Should the insertion function erase the already existing key/value pair and insert the new key/value pair?

Thanks :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`std::map::insert`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map/insert) returns an (iterator, boolean) pair. If the key was absent, it's inserted with the given value, and the function returns an iterator to it and `true` in the second component.

If the key was already present, the old value is preserved. The function returns an iterator to existing element, and `false` in the second component.

---

Starting from C++17, `std::map` also provides `insert_or_assign` member function. It behaves the same way, except that the old value is replaced with the new value when the key is already present.

Comment: Hey Igor. Thanks a lot. It does help:)

Comment: `insert_or_assign` ... from my SQL stored procedure days we'd have called that `upsert` but that's probably too whimsical for the committee these days.

Comment: Insert_or_assign is pretty clunky in comparison